# How to estimate the prediction power for a combination of MARS and CART model?

Tags: regression, cross-validation, predictive-models, cart, mars

I am trying to find a good model for my data to predict new values. My idea was to combine a MARS and a CART model (averaging the outcomes of both models). This method fits the Training data well. Now I want to get some statistics which show how good this combined model is concerning prediction.

How can I estimate the predictive power in this case? Is cross-validation useful?

Answer (score 0):

Boosting up till date is the most powerful way of combining CARTs.  If by some way you think a model is only an estimate and should have a standard error, then model averaging is a good idea.

Note that you can always fit the training data as much as you want (over-fitting). And you will never judge a model on how it fits the training.

Therefore cross-validation bootstrapping and other **out sample** techniques are the only way to access the predictive performance of a model.

The performance measure use in assessing a model also plays an important rule. *Predictive power* is not often used, as *power* usually refers to hypothesis testing. Predictive performance is a better term to use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to try the cross-validation procedure. But I have just the basis functions of the MARS and the decision tree of the CART. I really dont know how to implement the Cross Validation for the average model (I need to know how the basis functions and the tree look like when I change the training data?). Could you give me a hint?